# How can I speed up the rendering of items of a Recycler view thats taking FOREVER?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a Recycler view adapter that works. It just lists some contacts from an already made list. The thing is... it takes forever to list (or inflate?) them on screen. The app freezes for several seconds. It happens with phones tha have over 600 contacts. I thought it was just phone hardware limitations, but I don't experience any lag when I go to the native contacts list of the phone. That one loads in fractions of a second and is smooth. I just might be doing something wrong here.

```
class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private final int TYPE_NO_RESULTS = 0;
    private final int TYPE_ITEM_AFFILIATED = 2;
    private final int TYPE_ITEM_NONAFFILIATED = 4;
    private List<ContactData> contacts;

    public ContactAdapter(List<ContactData> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (contacts.size()>0){
            return controller.isSelectedAffiliated() ? TYPE_ITEM_AFFILIATED : TYPE_ITEM_NONAFFILIATED;
        }
        return TYPE_NO_RESULTS;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM_AFFILIATED || viewType == TYPE_ITEM_NONAFFILIATED){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_luka_contact_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ItemViewHolder(view);
        } else if (viewType == TYPE_NO_RESULTS){
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.view_transfer_contact_empty, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new NoResultsHolder(view);
        }
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final int type = getItemViewType(position);
        if (type == TYPE_ITEM_AFFILIATED || type == TYPE_ITEM_NONAFFILIATED){
            final ContactData data = getContactInfo(position);
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (controller.isSelectedAffiliated()) {
                        if (position<=contacts.size()){
                            mOnItemSelected.onContactSelected(data);
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
            ((ItemViewHolder)holder).titleView.setText(data.name);

            if (data.url!=null){
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(LukaContactsFragment.this.getContext().getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(data.url));
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable imageDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), bitmap);
                    imageDrawable.setCircular(true);
                    ((ItemViewHolder)holder).imageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    ((ItemViewHolder)holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(defaultImage);
                }
            } else {
                ((ItemViewHolder)holder).imageView.setImageBitmap(defaultImage);
            }

            ((ItemViewHolder) holder).inviteText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ((ItemViewHolder) holder).separator.setVisibility(position == contacts.size() || position== getItemCount()?View.INVISIBLE:View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            ((NoResultsHolder)holder).titleView.setText(getString(R.string.phone_transfer_contacts_no_results_header));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int count = 0;
        if (contacts.size()>0){
            count = contacts.size();
        }
        if (count== 0){
            count = 1;
        }
        return count;
    }

    private ContactData getContactInfo(int position) {
        return contacts.get(position);
    }

}
```

EDIT:Adding XML

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/listLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/contacts"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dimen_8"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/dimen_6"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_6"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure you’re only wrapping the list, not using weights to extend the list the complete size (so it should be match_parent, wrap_content), doing so will cause it to draw every view it has which could explain the long loading times

Comment: I tried to do that: Width (match parent) Height (wrap_content) and its still super slow

Comment: Could it be that requesting the items could be that’s taking so long? The two reasons I can think of would be its trying to draw all the views at once or it’s taking ages to load the items then drawing them

Comment: Yeah, I'm drawing everything at once. It might be that. Do you have an example of how to load by batches? Thanks for taking your time to answer btw!

Comment: Could you please post your layout file with the recyclerView in it so I can determine how to create your view :)

Comment: You mean the XML file right?

Comment: Yes that’s the one :)

Comment: ok just added it, thank you for your time again!

Comment: This is most likely NOT a problem with the rendering. From your description of the problem, it sounds like you may be fetching the contacts on the main thread, which will lock the UI until it is complete. Can you post the code that fetches the contacts list data?

Comment: It might also be a problem with the way you're loading the contacts' icon/avatar. If that `data.url` is not a local file, you are fetching it from the internet (with no caching, from what I can see) as you scroll the list. I would recommend that you use a library like Glide for this instead. https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: Hello Mike!  thanks for your time. The contact lists are already loaded in memory and the url are pointing to a default png atm that is stored inside the application.

If you look closely, the point in which I fetch the contact data is here: "final ContactData data = getContactInfo(position);" inside BindViewHolder. That method "return contacts.get(position);" in which "contacts" is a list already loaded filled and ready.

Comment: I would presume that Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Image... line is quite a heavy load as you’re parsing the URI on the fly, would it be better to pre-load those into the POJO when you first get the list and just reference it from the model instead of doing the Parsing each time?